# Visual Basic state tax calculator

Tags: vb.net

Im working on a visual basic project creating a tax calculator. Right now, i have two arrays, one for the states and one for the tax rates. States starting with A-L have the same tax rate of 2%, M-P 3.5%, and R-W 4%. Right now this is what the two arrays look like:

```
 Dim states() As String = {"Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
   "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", 
    "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", 
    "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
    "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", 
    "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New 
    York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
    "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
    "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
    "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"} 

    Dim statetax() As Double = {0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
    0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.035, 
    0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 
    0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 
    0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04}
```

Then, to calculate the state tax I have a bunch of If selectstate starts with "a" "b" "c" or "d" then totalstatetax = statetax(0) * income

I was wondering if there was a simplified version, or a way or creating an index that would allow the states and state tax to coincide. any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Use a dictionary?

Comment: Also -- is that really true or is this a toy problem? It would seem to be a stunning coincidence for alphabetical and tax-rate sorting of the states to agree like that.

Comment: no its a school assignment

Comment: You've greatly over-complicated this problem. If I were you, I'd scrap everything I had so far, carefully re-read the problem described in the third sentence of your post (only that sentence), and think about other ways you could possibly solve the problem of assigning one of three tax rates to groups of states (maybe thinking about similarities).

Comment: Hint:  Use `string.StartsWith` method.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary could be right tool for the job

```
var stateTaxes = new Dictionary<string, decimal>
{
    { "Alabama", 0.02m },
    { "Maine", 0.035m },
    // other states
}

var alabamaTaxAmount = income * stateTaxes["Alabama"];
```